# Удаление содержимого файла

Tags: python, файлы

Есть ли у файла метод удаления содержимого файла? Мне нужно не просто удалить файл, а именно удалить все содержимое файла, при этом, получается, должен остаться просто пустой файл. Пробовал через перезапись с пустой строкой но выдает ошибку

```
with open("text_here", "w") as f:
    f.write(")
```

> io.UnsupportedOperation: not writable

Comment: Достаточно просто открыть файл на запись. `open("text_here", "w")`.

Comment: а файл разрешен для записи? Если у вас права только на чтение то это уже проблематичнее.

Comment: В этом примере у вас кавычка не закрыта. В реальном коде так же?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ошибка

> io.UnsupportedOperation: not writable

говорит о том, что вы пытаетесь осуществить запись в дескриптор, который не предназначен для этого. Например, если открыли файл только на чтение (mode='r')

Как подсказывают в комментариях, достаточно просто открыть файл на запись:

```
with open('file.name', 'wb'):
    pass
```